# How to handle requests using different thread pools in Thrift?

Tags: thrift

I have a thrift service that has two methods
1. Response processSync(Request req)  : This method synchronously processes requests and returns a response. The client thread gets blocked until the request is completely processed by the server.
2. void processAsync(Request req)  : This method is for asynchronous processing. Here as soon as the server completely receives the request, the call returns with no output. Client thread does not wait until the request is processed by the server.

While using ThreadedSelectorServer that has separate threads for reading/writing and processing of threads. The requirement is to use separate thread pools at the method level. This is because it might happen that the all the processing threads get busy with synchronous requests. Clients using the asynchronous api might timeout. I wish to give both api's equal weightage so that if the server is flooded with sync requests; the async requests do not suffer.

Thought of having two different services, one with only sync method and another one with async. But in that case two thrift servers have to be started which shall require two different ports.I wish to avoid doing that.

Any suggestions how this can be achieved ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, use the **multiplex protocol** [introduced with Thrift 0.9.1](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/THRIFT-1915). It allows having multiple services sharing the same transport. Note that both server and client must use the multiplex protocol layer to succeed.

By the way, consider making the async method a **oneway**:

```
Service whatever {
  oneway void processAsync(1: Request req) 
}
```

Comment: Thanks Jen, So using TMultiplexedProcessor more than one services can be hosted on a single server. But how can I partition the number of processing threads per service. I mean say I have configured 10 threads for the thrift server and now further I need 6 threads should only handle service1 invocations and rest 4 threads handles service2 invocations. Is this possible ?

Comment: Why do you think should that be necessary? The operating system should be better at scheduling time slices between threads. Without knowing your exact scenario, expoerience tells that you probably only think that you know what's the best for your services. If you really need to throttle on a per-service Basis, I'd recommend to put requests into two queues and have a predefined number of threads per queue serving queue entries. But again, I don't think that you should do that. You are free to convince me by explaining the requirements/Scenario in more detail.

Comment: As I mentioned that there are two ways the service can be invoked     Sync and Async, There might be the case that clients calling the sync method may cause all processing threads to be busy for a long period of time. This shall effect the clients using the Async invocation.They may get error/exception stating that server is busy.This may happen when there's a burst of requests.  I went through the java docs of thrift 0.91 version but it seems currently there is no way to do this.