# Apache Thrift: Server with sync and async methods, it is possible?

Tags: java, thrift

I am trying to implement a twitter like service with client using java. I am using Apache thrift for RPC calls. The service uses a key-value store. I am trying to make the service fault-tolerant along with consistency and data-replication in the key-value store.

> For eg: suppose at a time, there are 10 servers running with id
>   S1,S2,S3 etc. and one client calls put(key,value) on S1, now S1 saves
>   this value and calls a RPC put(key,value) on all the remaining servers
>   for data-replication. I want the server method to save and return
>   success to client and also  start a thread with async calls on the
>   remaining 9 servers so that the client is not blocked during
>   replication.

The auto generated code has Iface and AsyncIface and I have currently implemented the Iface in a ServerHandler class.

My goal is to expose a backend server to the client and have normal (blocking) calls between a client and a server and async calls between servers. There will be multiple client-server pairs running at a time.

I understand, the data-replication model is crude but I am trying to learn distributed systems.

Can someone please help me with an example on how I can achieve this.

> Also, if you think my design is flawed and there are better ways in
>   which I can achieve data-replication using Apache Thrift please do
>   point out.

Thank You.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18911972/how-to-handle-requests-using-different-thread-pools-in-thrift   it seems this person has the done the same thing but I do not know how

Comment: Multiplex is different. It allows to run multiple services over the same transport stack. That's probably not what you are looking for with this question. It may be useful, though, if you want to combine a public service and the internal communication service, but (a) you are not forced to do so and (b) you may want to use different protocols/transports for public and internal services.

Answer (score 3):

A `oneway` method is asynchronous, any other method not marked with `oneway` is synchronous.

```
exception OhMyGosh {
    1: string msg
}

service TwelfthNightOrWhatYouWill {

    // A oneway method is a "one shot" method. The server may execute
    // it asynchronously, depending on the server implementation
    // Oneways can be very useful when used with messaging systems
    // A oneway does NOT return anything, including exceptions
    oneway void ImAsync(1: i32 foo, 2: string bar, 3: double baz)

    // Any method not marked with oneway is synchronous. Even if the call does
    // not return anything, it will be still a blocking call for the client.
    void ImSynchronous(1: i32 foo, 2: string bar) throws (1: OhMyGosh omg)
    i32  ImAsWell(1: double baz) throws (1: OhMyGosh omg)
    void MeToo()
}
```

Whether or not the server does execute the `oneway` asynchronously with regard to the connection, depends on what server implementation you use. A Threaded or Threadpool server seems a good choice.

After the client has sent his `oneway` request, it will not wait for reply from the server and just continue in his execution flow. Technically, for `oneway` no recv_Xxxx() function is generated, only the send_Xxx() part.

If you need data sent back to the client, the best option is to set up a server in the client process as well, which seems the optimal choice in your particular use case to me. In cases where this is not possible (think HTTP) the typical workarounds are polling or long-running calls, however both techniques come with some disadvantages.

---

<sub>[With apolagies to W.Shakespeare](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Twelfth_Night)</sub>